# SSRS Matrix Grouping - Per Measure

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Im trying to create a matrix report which contains 1 row group, 2 column groups with 2 measures...

At Present its grouping the measures under every group i.e

```
    Year 1    Year1     Year1    Year1
    Month1    Month1    Month 2  Month 2
    Value 1   Value 2   Value 1  Value 2
```

I would like this to group into each measure (similar to adding the values before the column in a pivottable) so it appears like below

```
    Year1     Year1      Year1     Year1
    Month1    Month2     Month 1   Month 2
   Value 1    Value 1    Value 2   Value 2
```

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Appologies, After messing around with the groups and deleting the unwanted gaps i managed to create the adjacent column and child group which has done the trick